# Solr Document Tagging

Tags: algorithm, apache, solr

I am working with Solr and my need is to tag documents that are indexed based on the content that resides within the documents. I am thinking of using KEA for extracting key phrases. So i wanted to know is there any way of integrating KEA with Apache Solr and give the  required solution. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is writing an UpdateRequestProcessor. I did that using MAUI, which is basically a kea++ and it has been pretty easy.

more information here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor

I strongly suggest you the UIMA integration too